# Change options in same select based on selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you can see first option (Option 1) is selected by default. What I want to do is if I select Option 2 to change their places (add Option 1 to list and set selected Option 2).

```
<select id="type" name="type" class="selectpicker" title="Option 1" value="1">
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**My try:**

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
     var currentOptionValue = $('select option:selected').text();

     if (currentOptionValue == 'Option 2') {
         $(".selectpicker option[value="Option 2"]").text('Option 1');
     }
});
```

Comment: OK, but I don't want to see currently selected option in options (dropdown). How can I do that?

Comment: $(".selectpicker option[value="Option 2"]").text('Option 1'); /// it isn't change their places but change the visual text

Comment: pls can you update your question with what you really want?

Comment: Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/37yu8zn1/) do you want this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/52/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki can you add this as answer so I can accept it. Great job man. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/52/)**.

I think that what you looking for :

```
$('.selectpicker').change(function() {
     var oldOptionText  = $('.selectpicker').attr('title');
     var oldOptionValue = $('.selectpicker').attr('value');

     var currentOptionText  = $('select option:selected').text();
     var currentOptionValue = $('select option:selected').attr('value');

     $('select option:selected').text(oldOptionText);
     $('select option:selected').attr('value', oldOptionValue);

     $('.selectpicker').attr('title', currentOptionText);
     $('.selectpicker').attr('value', currentOptionValue);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. But it seems the top option isn't selectable? (ie if Option 1 is selected, and option 2 is the top option in the select box, you can only select option 3)

Comment: Yes, i see i'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are loking for something like that?

```js
   $('.selectpicker').change(function() {
     var currentOptionValue = $('select option:selected').text();

     if (currentOptionValue == 'Option 2') {
      $(".selectpicker").append(("<option>Option 1</option>"));

     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type" name="type" class="selectpicker" title="Option 1" value="1">
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```